# Constructing objects that extends a super class that has its own constructor

Tags: php, constructor, polymorphism

I was unsure what to call this so feel free to edit the title.

I am trying to create my own API. within this API there are certain objects these objects all extends the super class `ApiObject`:

```
    class ApiObject {
    protected $sqltemplate;
    public function __construct($db){
        $this->sqltemplate = new sqlTemplates($db);
    }

    protected function getTemplate(){
        return $this->sqltemplate;
    }

}
```

Now an example of the objects that extends this class is:

```
class Group extends ApiObject {


public function __construct(){

}

public function findByUserId(){

}

public function findByTeam(){

}
```

Now my question is as follow:

When i construct a type of the `Group` object is the `ApiObject`'s contructor always called? and if so how does it pass the parameter `$db` to the constructor?

Comment: You must pass the `$db` to your `Group` constructor as well and call `super.__construct($db)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have all the code, why don't you just try it?

```
<?php
class ApiObject {
    public function __construct($db){
        echo __METHOD__, "($db)\n";
    }
}

class Group extends ApiObject {
    public function __construct(){
            echo __METHOD__, "\n";
    }
}

new Group;
```

outputs

```
Group::__construct
```

This shows that the constructor of the parent object is not called automatically. You have to do this via `parent::__construct($db)` and add the `$db` parameter to the second constructor.

```
<?php
class ApiObject {
    public function __construct($db){
        echo __METHOD__, "($db)\n";
    }
}

class Group extends ApiObject {
    public function __construct($db){
            echo __METHOD__, "\n";
            parent::__construct($db);
    }
}

new Group("db");
```

outputs

```
Group::__construct
ApiObject::__construct(db)
```

For a better understanding: `Group::__construct` overwrites the parent constructor, that's the reason you have to call it manually. If you don't specify a constructor, the parent constructor is called automatically. Example:

```
<?php
class ApiObject {
    public function __construct($db){
        echo __METHOD__, "($db)\n";
    }
}

class Group extends ApiObject {
}

new Group("db");
```

outputs

```
ApiObject::__construct(db)
```